# React Native Configuration Return Error 500, Followed React Native Docs

Tags: react-native, mobile-development, react-native-cli

I have followed all instruction as in docs, but couldn't start my first react native app.Node -v v8.11.4,  npm 4.6.1, react-native-cli 2.0.1

See Error Image Here:

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: delete node modules and use npm install again. let me now if still not working

Comment: @anilsidhu still facing the same issue

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20331 , react-native version 0.56.0  is buggy for windows, got any other version as react-native init myApp --version 0.55.4  See above link for further description.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the watchman cache and delete the node_modules folder and re-install it by using `npm install`.
If it still not works try updating your RN version to the latest one.